# Can Brazil residence permit holder enter Schengen area without visa?

Tags: schengen, mexico, brazil, argentina

Citizens of Brazil can enter the area visa free (90 days within a 180-day period). But not sure about residents of Brazil.

If you don't know the answer, you can reply for Argentina or Mexico since I believe they have similar policies.

Comment: Have you tried https://skyteam.traveldoc.aero/ ?

Answer (score 17):

No, unless the citizenship of the residence permit holder allows this.

Schengen has a special case for residence permit holders of *other Schengen states*, but generally speaking they go by citizenship. The residence permit might make it much easier to get a visa, but a visa would still be required.

Comment: Keep in mind that it's not necessarily true for all of the Schengen area. Brazil is part of the CPLP (or CPLC in English), which means that for Brazilians staying for less than 180 days within Portugal, there is no Visa requirement to enter the country (which is part of the Schengen area)

Comment: @Oak I think this was a CPLP proposal, I don't think Brazilians do get 180 days in Portugal, but rather 90, and they get it across Schengen in general. Citizens of other CPLP countries like Cape Verde or Angola, need a visa to enter Portugal. There are other Schengen countries that do have specific visa arrangements with third countries, beyond Schengen. But even if there was such a rule, it would almost certainly be implemented on the basis of citizenship, not residency, the vast majority of visa rules are.

Answer (score 4):

It's not so much the citizenship or residence that matters, but the passport that you are using for travel. If you are travelling with a Brazilian passport, then you should be allowed to enter without a visa, just like other Brazilian passport holders.

If using another passport, you should check the [list of countries whose nationals are exempted from holding a visa](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/default/files/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/apply_for_a_visa/docs/visa_lists_en.pdf). Argentina or Mexico passport holders, would not need a visa.

This is not specific to Brazil, by the way. Even a resident of an European Union country outside the Schengen zone, *might* still need to apply for a visa to enter a Schengen country.

Comment: That is wrong. You are right that an EU citizen needs to show EU citizenship to enter without a visa, but an EU citizen couldn't get a visa on a non-EU passport if he or she discloses the dual nationality. Generally, one is not allowed get around visa laws (for good or for bad) by neglecting to mention multiple citizenships).

Comment: I didn't suggest that an EU citizen would get a visa on a non-EU passport automatically. And I'm certainly not suggesting bypassing visa laws. Multiple nationalities must be disclosed if requested in the form. My point was, even if you are an EU citizen, if you travel with a passport of another country that needs a visa, you will still be required to apply for a visa to enter the EU. I'll remove that sentence since it can be a source of confusion.

Comment: I don't think a Schengen visa can be granted to an EU citizen, no matter what other passports he or she has.

Comment: The first sentence of this answer's second paragraph is also incorrect. A traveler must satisfy the admission and visa rules of the _destination country_, not the country that issued the passport.

Comment: And you are confusing passport holders and citizens. I don't know about Brasil, and although it is not common, some countries also issue passports to non-citizens, for example UK. Having a UK passport is not a proof that you are a UK citizen and entry requirements are usually (if not always) bound to your citizenship and not to which countries you hold passports from.

Comment: Good point, I'd consider that an exception and I'm not sure how exactly it's handled. My answer is given based on the passport country and citizenship being the same. In any case, I'd always advise people to check with relevant authorities and official information before making travel plans.

Comment: >I don't think a Schengen visa can be granted to an EU citizen, no matter what other passports he or she has.
It's unusual, but it's certainly possible.

Comment: @Nagev In which cases do you claim it is possible to grant a Schengen visa to an EU citizen? The Schengen visa code does not contain any legal provision for doing so.

Comment: A Schengen visa would not technically be granted to EU citizens, since they don't need a visa to enter the EU. However, in a very exceptional circumstance, if a national of country A is only in possession of a passport of nationality A, e.g. it's the only current travel document with no EU passport or ID issued yet, that person could request a visa on the passport of country A, if it is required for citizens of country A, while declaring his/her additional EU citizenship. I think we're going beyond the scope of the question though.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not making any claims. People should always check with the relevant authorities and official information before making travel plans,  also because things can change, so it's best to get the most up to date information directly from official sources.