# Can I travel to Mexico with Italian residence permit?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, mexico, italian-residents, residence-permits

I am a Indian citizen with an Italian residence permit (Polizia di Stato). I would like to travel to Mexico. I don't have a visa. Will my Italian residence permit (valid for 2 years, not unlimited) allow me to enter Mexico?

Comment: TL;DR - Unless you have a permanent resident, no.

Comment: @AnishSheela I don’t think that’s true. A ‘visa valida’ is sufficient.

Comment: @Traveller See TIMATIC - https://www.traveldoc.aero/?SC=1|ITA|MEX|2022-10-18&SC=2|MEX|ITA|2022-11-01&D=1|IND|IND|2023-10-18&D=6|ITA|ITA|2023-10-18&results=true

Comment: @AnishSheela Well that is confusing, the Mexican Government website https://www.inm.gob.mx/gobmx/word/index.php/paises-requieren-visa-para-mexico/ states holders of a) PR and b) visas of certain countries do not need a visa to enter Mexico I’d recommend the OP contacts them to check mailto:atenciontelefonica@inami.gob.mx

Comment: @AnishSheela Using the link in your comment, and entering ‘visa’ instead of ‘residence permit’ returns the answer ‘authorized to board’ https://www.traveldoc.aero/results. Assuming the RP held by the OP is equivalent to a ‘valid visa’, of course

Comment: @Traveller That's confusing for me also. Visa has much more lower ties to the country than residence permit. The wikipedia page also specifically forbids residence permit, but allows visa.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139936/discussion-between-traveller-and-anish-sheela).

Comment: @AnishSheela Presumably Mexico does not think someone with *any* valid visa from Schengen, Canada etc poses much of an immigration risk

Comment: Other duplicates: [Can Brazil residence permit holder enter Schengen area without visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/166354/19400) and [Mexican visa for Finnish residence permit holder](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/90960/19400) and related [Can a temporary Dutch resident enter Mexico without a visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/95129/19400)