# Visa-free travel to Mexico - UK Residence Card under EU Settlement Scheme (vs Biometric Residence Permit)

Tags: visas, uk, mexico, eu-citizens, uk-residents

I am a EU citizen living in the EU with settled status. My wife is a third-country National, but equally has settled status under the EUSS scheme, and was issued a permanent "Residence Card".

However, there seems to be slight legal distinction between such a residence card (BRC) and a residence permit (BRP). That is, to the best of my understanding, the only available option for EU family members is a card that says "Residence Card" on top, whereas immigrants from non-EU countries would be issued a "Residence Permit". [[1]](https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits) [[2]](https://immigrationbarrister.co.uk/the-eu-settlement-scheme-can-i-have-a-biometric-residence-card/)

Some of the language about Visa-free travel to Mexico refers to permanent residents who are holders of a BRP. However, this may be old language, or language that is simply unaware of the distinction. For example, I've seen this:

> "A visa exemption applies if you hold BRP Permanent Resident status in
> the UK "ILR" or a valid B1/B2 USA visa."

There is language that is [possibly ambiguous](https://embamex.sre.gob.mx/finlandia/index.php/traveling/visas):

> If you are a citizen in the Schengen Area, UK, USA, Canada or Japan or
> if you have a permanent residence permit or a valid visa for any of
> those countries

And finally, there is also language that only makes reference to "permanent
residence" with no additional qualifiers:

> According to Mexican regulations which came into force in June 2009,
> those with ILR / ILE or PERMANENT RESIDENTS of the United Kingdom
> wishing to travel to Mexico do not require a visa to enter the country
> as a tourist or business visitor for up to 180 days

The Mexican embassy does not seem interested in specifically answering this question, and responds with copy&pasted statements.

Out of an abundance of caution - should we expect any problems?

Comment: What citizenship(s) do you and your wife hold?  You mention you are EU citizens, so I'm unsure why "...citizen in the Schengen Area, UK, USA, Canada or Japan..." doesn't fit for you

Comment: This rule ignores the group of peaple between a visitor visa and those who have been residents for longer than 5 years (permanent). Since your mexican link later states that at the port of entry the card **must** have 'the word “Permanent” stated in their residence permit', that it will be checked. Does your spouse need a Schengen Visa, which is issued free of charge and immediately to spouses of EU citizens? If yes, get one to fulfill the mexican condition.  Otherwise a mexican visa must be applied for.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/176973/can-i-travel-to-mexico-with-italian-residence-permit

Comment: @Midavalo Apologies, I should have made that more clear - my wife is not a EU citizen. Post updated.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I'm not sure if I understand. My wife's UK residence card does have the word 'permanent' on it. You are right that she could get a a Schengen Visa to fulfill one of the conditions , but even an EU-family based on needs you getting an appointment at TLS which can take weeks. Getting the Mexican one is likely easier.